# ASP.NET web forms retrieving specific user car adverts in GridView

Tags: sql, asp.net, database, gridview, information-retrieval

My idea was to create a stored procedure and use in grid view  but how would i  get userid to search with from database then input into the procedure to do this?

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[seller_car]
 @userID VARCHAR(50)

 AS
 SELECT * FROM cars,pictures
 WHERE cars.car_ID = pictures.car_ID
 AND cars.user_ID = @userID;


 RETURN 



[car_ID]               INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[make]                 VARCHAR (20)   NULL,
[model]                VARCHAR (20)   NULL,
[colour]               VARCHAR (20)   NULL,
[price]                DECIMAL (6, 2) NULL,
[year_of_registration] INT            NULL,
[user_ID]              INT            NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([car_ID] ASC),
FOREIGN KEY ([user_ID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[users] ([user_ID])
```

Comment: do you wanna get UserId from Gridview ?

Comment: need more description

Comment: do you need to input the userid to the stored procedure for retrive the data??

Comment: Yes that is correct,i want to get the user id and input into stored procedure that  has been used to configure gridview so it will only display cars that belong to that user id.